# How to start reading CSV from beginning again?

Tags: csv, perl

```
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new;
open my $fh, "test.csv" or die "test.csv: $!";

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
    my @fields = @$row;
    if ($fields[0] eq "A1") {
        print "Found A1", "\n";
        last;
    }
}
# now start searching the CSV again
```

If I have gone through some of a CSV using [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS), how can I then start again from the beginning?  Is there some way to return the pointer/window to the beginning of the file?

Answer (score 0):

```perl
use Fcntl qw( SEEK_SET );

seek($fh, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

You could also just re-open the file.